# django rest framework create for self.request.user.<model>

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have `Folder` model. `Folder` has `foreignkey` to `User` called `folders`.

In django rest framework I would like to create new `Folder` object. How do I specify "create object at self.request.user.folders"? under current (out of the box vanilla `ModelViewSet`) implementation I get error:

> folder.folder.user_id may not be NULL

This indicates that a we are trying to create `Folder` object is without specifying a `user`.

Is there a built in way or will I need to override the `create` method and pass `user` in to the serializer as a argument?

Note that we don't want to pass `user_id` in `request.DATA` due to security issues.

models.py:

```
class FolderModel(Model):
    user = ForeignKey(User, related_name='folders')
    title = CharField(max_length=100)
```

views.py:

```
class FolderView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = serializers.FoldereSerializer
    model = FolderModel

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.request.user.folders.all()
```

Comment: Please show the relevant models, so we can clearly see all relations.

Comment: @mariodev I have made the updates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fom the [docs](http://django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions.html)`:

```
def pre_save(self, obj):
    obj.owner = self.request.user
```

Answer (score 1):

The original answer no longer works as of DRF 3.0, as the functions have changed. The relevant doc is [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.0-announcement/#changes-to-prepost-save-hooks).

From the docs:

> The pre_save and post_save hooks no longer exist, but are replaced with perform_create(self, serializer) and perform_update(self, serializer).
>
> These methods should save the object instance by calling serializer.save(), adding in any additional arguments as required. They may also perform any custom pre-save or post-save behavior.
>
> For example:

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    # Include the owner attribute directly, rather than from request data.
    instance = serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
    # Perform a custom post-save action.
    send_email(instance.to_email, instance.message)
```